# How do I keep an IQueryable<> within a transaction using the repository pattern?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, transactions, iqueryable

According to NHProf, the use of implicit transactions is discouraged:

http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions

However, NHibernate LINQ returns an `IQueryable<>` when reading objects from the database, and this is lazily evaluated. I have this method in a repository:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    using (var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var data = _session.Linq<T>();
        transaction.Commit();
        return data;
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the method will commit the transaction before `data` is evaluated. Is there a way to use the repository pattern and keep the `IQueryable<>` in an explicit transaction? Or is it acceptable for read operations to use implicit transactions?

Comment: Why would you want a transaction around a read operation?

Comment: Ah, from the article: "Even if we are only reading data, we should use a transaction, because using transactions ensures that we get consistent results from the database. NHibernate assumes that all access to the database is done under a transaction, and strongly discourages any use of the session without a transaction."  However, I still don't at all understand why the author is making this declamation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repository should **not** create a transaction. That's a responsibility of a separate layer (which depends on the application type).

Comment: I agree, I guess your explanation why you think it is the responsibility of a separate layer is something like: Transactions boundaries should be defined by the way of the user or other applications interacting with the application. Example for web applications per request, for services per service call, for windows applications per "click in on a button", for games per move, etc. When the transactions are created by the repository, it will be much harder to make the repository independent from the way the application is interacting with it, and also might make it harder to use in general.

Answer (score 3):

I'd refactor this to allow external transaction control. The Repository cannot know the scope of the unit of work that various read/write calls are a part of unless the code that makes the calls tells it. Consider setting up a "unit of work" pattern: without revealing specific details of the data store implementation, allow objects that depend on Repository to specify that they are beginning, aborting or completing a "unit of work".

```
public interface IRepository
{
   public UnitOfWork BeginUnitOfWork()

   public void CommitUOW(UnitOfWork unit)

   public void AbortUOW(UnitOfWork unit)

   public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>(UnitOfWork unit)

   public List<T> GetAll<T>()

   public void Store<T>(T theObject, UnitOfWork unit)

   public void Store<T>(T theObject)
}
```

Your Repository would probably implement this by maintaining a private Dictionary of SQL transactions, each keyed to a UnitOfWork object (this can be as simple as an empty instantiable class, or it can provide framework-agnostic information about state or metrics). When performing a DB operation, your callers will first ask to begin a UoW, and they will be given a token that they will use to identify the context within which they are making a DB call. The object that gets the token can pass it to other classes that need to perform DB operations in the same operational context. The unit of work will remain open until the dependent class tells the Repository that it is finished, allowing lazy-loads and atomic multi-operation procedures.

Notice that there are overloads that do not require units of work. It is possible, and perhaps necessary, to make simple calls without explicitly starting a unit of work. In these cases, your Repository can create an internal UOW, perform the requested operation, and return the results. However, lazy-loading will be difficult or impossible in these cases; you will have to retrieve the entire result set into a List before ending the internal UoW.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Diego on this one - repository can't know the transaction scope.

I also have a concern about returning IQueryable - as I understand it, it has a ton of extra query methods that might be very difficult to unit test. I prefer returning IEnumerable and encapsulate more complex queries in repository methods. Otherwise, you'll have to unit test all kinds of variations of queries against the output of GetAll().

Comment: Is it really your job to unit test all the methods on IQueryable? Shouldn't you only be unit testing code that you wrote?

Comment: @Gabe: My concern isn't unit-testing IQueryable, it's unit testing the _results_ of queries used in the myriad places. I have read others say it's 6-of-1 as to where the query logic lives, but I much prefer a method like GetFulfilledOrders() over a complicated linq query to return the same thing. Easier to test and clearer.